# mongoose fulltext search not working

Tags: node.js, search, mongoose, full-text-search

i have a problem with index in mongoose
My model

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 


var commentSchema = new Schema({
   
    customer_id: String,
    motel_id: String,
    customer_name: String,
    content: String,
    created_at: Date


});
commentSchema.set('autoIndex', false);
commentSchema.index(
    {'$**': 'text'}
)

var comments  = mongoose.model("comments", commentSchema);
```

and my search function

```js
function testIndex(req, res) {
    var searchString = "h";
    comment.find({$text: {$search: searchString}})
    .skip(20)
    .limit(10)
    .exec(function(err, docs) { res.send("docs:" + docs); });
}
```

but it don't return any value. How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please refer this link**
  [1]: [Best way to perform a full text search in MongoDB and Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775051/best-way-to-perform-a-full-text-searc)`enter code here`h-in-mongodb-and-mongoose

Comment: i'm using mlab to store my db. Does it avoid indexes, i have the same code in your example but it's not working