# CosmosDB mongoDB API sort and full text search throwing error

Tags: mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using CosmosDB MongoDB API for store and retrieval of documents in the collections.

I am trying to use the sort collection.find({}).sort({field1: 1}  and seeing this error:

```
"message": "Failed to retrieve the document:MongoError: Error=2, Details='Response status code does not indicate success: 
BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: d05b7772-3252-4005-898f-4480cadfb8e1; Reason: 
(Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 
d05b7772-3252-4005-898f-4480cadfb8e1; Reason: (Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); 
Substatus: 0; ActivityId: d05b7772-3252-4005-898f-4480cadfb8e1; Reason: (Message: {\"Errors\":
[\"The index path corresponding to the specified order-by item is excluded.\"]}\r\nActivityId: d05b7772-3252-4005-898f-4480cadfb8e1, 
Request URI: /apps/e118124c-80f3-408e-a2f9-fbea51664ad4/services/5cb63213-f046-49d6-9825-0bfa4010772e/partitions
/68271031-2d85-44cd-9929-8857ff69b63e/replicas/132696733163313635s/, 
RequestStats: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tracing.TraceData.ClientSideRequestStatisticsTraceDatum, 
SDK: Windows/10.0.17763 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.18.0);););"
```

Does it mean without having an index, we can not do a sort on MongoDB?

Wondering is this the MongoDB behavior or the CosmosDB behavior? Not sure.

Second issue is: I want to have a string search across all fields, like this:

```
 collection.find({"$text":{"$search":"findMeOut"}});
```

However here I am seeing this Mongo Error:

```
MongoError: $text not supported
```

Now what this means?

I am using CosmosDB MongoDB API using JavaScript and and NodeJs native MongoClient with the following versions:

```
 "mongodb": "^3.6.10",
 "fastify-mongodb": "^2.0.1",
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sharing your model will really help. AFAIK, in order to use the text search, you've to index the fields you wanna perform search on with index name *text*. You can take a look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775051/best-way-to-perform-a-full-text-search-in-mongodb-and-mongoose) which is similar to your problem I believe